# vagrant+docker unable to access docker instances using private network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vagrant, docker-network, vagrant-windows

I've created VirtualBox VM via Vagrant using ubuntu-18.04 image and installed `docker-ce` and `docker-compose`. The VM has NAT and private network.  Below is the Vagrant file.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
  config.vm.define "kp-ms"
  config.vm.hostname = "kp-ms"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.64.10", netmask: "255.255.254.0"
  config.vm.synced_folder "./data", "/data"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = false
    vb.memory = "4096"
    vb.name = "kp-ms"
    vb.check_guest_additions = false
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nicpromisc2", "allow-all"]
  end

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL

    apt-get update
    apt-get upgrade -y
    apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
    apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
    add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
    curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

    sudo docker network create -d macvlan \
          --subnet=192.168.64.0/23 \
          --ip-range=192.168.64.192/28 \
          -o macvlan_mode=bridge \
          -o parent=enp0s8.10 mac10

    sudo ip link add mac10 link enp0s8.10 type macvlan mode bridge
    sudo ip addr add 192.168.64.193/28 dev mac10
    sudo ifconfig mac10 up

    sudo docker-compose -f /data/docker-compose.yml up -d
  SHELL
end
```

and 
**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    networks:
      kp-net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.64.200
networks:
  kp-net:
    external: true
    name: mac10
```

As shown in above docker-compose file, I've provided a static IP to docker instance, which falls in private network subnet and created the docker network with macvlan with bridging to private network. 
With the above network I'm able to ping to docker instance from guest VM, however I'm unable to ping to Docker Instance from Host Machine(in my case its Windows 10)

From packet analysis I find that ARP for docker instance doesn't(No ARP replay) get resolved. How to access docker instances from host machine using IP address? I'm not looking for port forwarding, as this docker-compose is sample one, docker-compose has 4-5 additional service. I tried using `ovs-docker` problem with this is, can't set additional network for communication between docker instances.